# How do I config html input for verification code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have verification code that is just a 4 digit number (e.g. 3253)
I need the user to type it from its mobile device.

[image]

```html
<input inputmode="numeric"  maxlength="4"  placeholder="Code" />
```

Something like this works but I can still type "`.`" and "`,`" on my Android device.

How do I prevent those bad boys ("`.`", "`,`")?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
<input inputmode="numeric"  maxlength="4"  placeholder="Code" onkeypress='validate(event)' />
```

```
function validate(evt) {

            var theEvent = evt || window.event;
            if (theEvent.type === 'paste') {
                key = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
            } else {
                var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
                key = String.fromCharCode(key);
            }

            var regex = /[0-9]|\./;

            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                theEvent.returnValue = false;
                if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
            }

        }
```

or

```
<input type=text onkeypress="return /^-?[0-9]*$/.test(this.value+event.key)">
```